# Why display property depends on the position property in my example?

Tags: css

I am playing with an example where a pseudo-element is used in the link element in order to create a colorful background to a link content(text). And I started tweaking the position of the ::before from absolute to relative which caused the colorful background rectangle to disappear and than come back accordingly. As I do it the in the Firefox developer tools I noticed that when the background is present the display property of the ::before element is also set to block - not surprisingly. If I set the position to relative then the background rectangle disappears and the display property of the ::before element is automatically set to inline. And I was curious why tweaking the position property affects the display property?

```
a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  inset: 2px;
  background: cyan;
}
```